# ScalaTemplate to handle JsObject

Tags: json, scala, rest

i am trying to access the JsObject i send as a response from server in scala view.
How can i do that???

```
@(user: play.api.libs.json.JsObject)
@main("title"){
  @user.\("fieldname")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses around the expression that extracts the field from the JsObject:

```
  @(user.\("fieldname"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank u for the answer

```
@user.value.get("username")
```

it worked for me as well